# Docker Container for a Django app using uwsgi + nginx

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose, uwsgi

So I am trying to get my django app to work in a Docker container. However it seems that I am not even close to success... The error, that I keep getting is: **You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP**.

And as I am using MySql, I am also using docker-compose to link the 2 containers.

The certificates are made with OpenSSL. I am fairly new to nginx + uwsgi but I read a lot on it and yet I did not manage to get it working on my own...

Comment: is that socket correct ?  server unix:///app/app.sock; # for a file socket with 3 slash. ?

Comment: Well, I did use [nginx+uwsgi tutorials](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) and there it was written with 3 slashes.

Comment: The error u are getting is from nginx?

Comment: Well after starting the containers with `docker-compose up` when I try to visit the site, I get the error. I assume it's either from nginx or uwsgi eventhough I did my best to set up both properly.

Comment: check nginx logs first.

Comment: Well I checked the logs of the container and it says: **You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.** , **code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\xa7\x01\x00\x00\xa3\x03\x03\xb53\x99\xad*E\xaa\x13\x15)')**

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your Django settings:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_PROXY_FORW_PROTO', 'https')
```

And add this in your nginx location/{}:

```
proxy_set_header X-Proxy-Forw-Proto $scheme;
```

That way Nginx can tell Django the request was HTTPS (cause Django doesn't see the original request) and Django can handle it correctly (more info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header)).

Comment: I do have `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_PROXY_FORW_PROTO', 'https')` in my settings.py file and I added the following code `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` and `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;` to my nginx config 10-15 minutes after posting yet it didnt work.

Comment: Did you use the same variable name in SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER and proxy_set_header?

Comment: That may be the problem. How can I check if I have ?

Comment: Look at my example: HTTP_X_PROXY_FORW_PROTO and X-Proxy-Forw-Proto. Same name, with HTTP_ in front in Django

Comment: I changed them and yet it is still not working. I just edited my post with the last line added for nginx conf.

Comment: Your Nginx and Django are on the same machine?

Comment: Also, it is strange that your Nginx speaks on socket, and Django listens using runserver. Shouldn't you use uwsgi --socket mysite.sock --wsgi-file wsgi.py instead?

Comment: Oh, I do use uwsgi but I didn't post the uwsgi.ini as it is kinda standard. I also use supervisord to get both going. Should I remove the command for runserver from my docker-compose.yml and should I post the uwsgi.ini ?

Comment: If you have set the uwsgi.ini properly, I think you should replace the runserver command with "uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini" to use it. I don't use socket files i my setup (I use "proxy_pass http://app;" in Nginx), but if you wanna post it, I'm happy to try help and learn

Comment: I do use supervisord who starts up uwsgi and nginx, so thats why I haven't included it in my docker-compose.yml

Comment: If you replace 443 by 80 in your Nginx config and comment the 3 ssl param lines, does it work with normal http? (would be a good way to make sure django is connected properly)

Comment: Well now when I removed the `runserver` command from my docker-compose.yml it seems to have stopped working and the issue is in uwsgi as I am getting **INFO gave up: app-uwsgi entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly**.

Comment: Ok, try running your Django with "uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi", and in Nginx, set the upstream to yourIP:8000 and replace the content of location / with proxy_pass http://app;
  
    
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Proxy-Forw-Proto $scheme;

Comment: proxy_pass h ttp://django (http with no space, had to put it cause it is remove otherwise)

Comment: Well, after doing what you said above, the uwsgi-app no longer exits but I get the same error for nginx now.

Comment: you replaced mysite.wsgi by the correct name of your Django app, right?

Comment: After adding http://django to the proxy pass I no longer get the error for the nginx, however once I try to enter http://192.168.99.100:443/ I get:400 Bad Request

The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Comment: don't use 443 again, cause you'd have both Django and Nginx listening to the same port (if they are on same machine, which I guess from your configs). use port 8000 for Django (in both uwgsi command in Django and upstream config of Nginx)

Comment: can you update what you Nginx and Docker-Compose look like now?

Comment: Ok, I changed the port in docker-compose.yml to 8000:8000 and now when I enter http://192.168.99.100:8000/ I get **Internal Server Error**

Comment: I have edited how docker-compose.yml and nginx.conf look like at the moment.

Comment: for web, you still have "command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:443". Can you replace that with uwsgi --http :8000 --module mysite.wsgi, mysite being the name of your Django app

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I totally missed it. In my docker-compose.yml I removed it the first time you told me to and I wrote [program:app-uwsgi]
`command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --http :8000 --module webapp.wsgi` in my supervisord.conf file

Comment: Ok, Nginx and Django are in the same container, right? It had missed that. Wouldn't it be better to put Nginx in another container? Do you have any logs in your container that explain the Internal Server Error you talked about?

Comment: Well, I had them in different containers, but I read somewhere that if they are in different containers there may be problems with the socket. After typing `docker logs <container name>` I get no information for the **Internal Server Error**.

Comment: I have them all in different containers, and it is working great with proxy_pass and the ip:port upstream config. The point is to be able to have 1 Nginx container as entry point, which then loadbalances your requests on several django containers (which will be on several servers in production)... but that is a point for later lol. First thing is to fix the problem. Was your django app working properly before you migrate it to docker?

Comment: Try to remove the Nginx part for now in supervisord, and only start your django app. Then try to access it on port 8000 (for example the admin interface of the app) and see if that works

Comment: Well, yes but without the nginx+uwsgi part - I implemented them later on, which I guess may have not been the smartest idea.

Comment: I removed the Nginx part of the supervisord and used `docker-compose up` yet when I visit http://192.168.99.100:8000/ I still get the same error: **Internal Server Error**

Comment: Ok, in Django settings, do you have DEBUG = True

and TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG?

Comment: And did you set any logging settings?

Comment: I had `DEBUG = True` and I am missing `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG`. I just added it but it changed nothing.

Comment: Under Logging I have set handlers and loggers.

Comment: you run docker-compose up or docker-compose up -d? If first one, do you see any error in the outputs?

Comment: and then once your containers are running, type "docker exec -it web /bin/bash*", and then type "cat the/path/to/your/django/logs", where the path to your django logs is the one you've set in your settings for the "django" logger

Comment: I haven't set anything for the .log files of the loggers. Can the issue be caused from MySQL as today I did have some problems with it.

Comment: you can go check in the mysql container if you want "docker exec -it db /bin/bash*" and then check if the database is created, but Django should shout an error if it did not find the DB

Comment: do you have a django logger in your loggins settings? if not, create it, it is very useful: 'django': {
            'handlers':['djangofile'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'INFO',
        }, where djangofile is a handler that you set to write in logs/django.log for example

Comment: So I added what you said under loggers +      `'djangofile': {
            'filename': 'logs/django.log'` under handlers

Comment: Now try to reach ip:8000 and do in web container to see if there is something in logs/django.log

Comment: There is nothing in django.log. I may, however, done something wrong.

Comment: you checked in the container, right? i mean after "docker exec -it web /bin/bash*"? If yes, let's see if someone finds an obvious thing we missed. If your app was working before, it is strange that it doesn't anymore! Did you check in the db container if the DB has been created properly? It is time for bed for me, good luck for now!

Comment: I checked the logs in the container and I checked the db and it seems fine. Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: I guess next thing we can look at tomorrow is how you build and start your web container. are you familiar with that? (and yw, I hate when something that seems simple does not work lol)

Comment: Well, I tried a couple of things when it comes to that. I did `docker-compose up` and also tried `docker-compose up -d db` followed by `sleep 10` followed by `docker-compose up -d web`.

Comment: Quick update - I no longer get **Internal Server Error**, however, the site does not load and I get - **ERR_TIMED_OUT**. On the bright side when I open Kitematic (I use docker toolbox as I am on windows) under Web Preview the site is visible.

Comment: I never used docker on windows. Try to replace the last 3 lines of your dockerfile with 
ADD start.sh /usr/local/bin/start.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start.sh
WORKDIR /app
CMD start.sh

Then create a start.sh file next to your web Dockerfile, and write in there
# wait 30 seconds so that the DB can start - can be cleaner with a connection test, but should be enough for now
sleep 30

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate auth --noinput
python manage.py migrate --noinput
uwsgi --http :8000 --module webapp.wsgi

Comment: What is the difference between using start.sh and supervisord? Because I did try before to use start.sh as an entrypoint, however, my attempt was not successful.

Comment: start.sh is just a script that we tell docker to run when starting the image. And we create that script with the commands for database migration and uwsgi start up in it. That removes all the supervisord overhead. All i'm trying to do with this is simplify the command to see if it works

Comment: Well, I replaced the last line in start.sh with `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --http :8000 --module webapp.wsgi`. It did run, however, the migrations were unsuccessful and something that caught my eye is : *WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='')*. So after running it, nothing changed. The site still refuses to load.

Comment: A quick question that I have is, when nginx is not being used right now, should `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_PROXY_FORW_PROTO', 'https')` be there?

Comment: It shouldn't matter to leave it here. your wsgi file is in /app/webapp/wsgi.py?

Comment: That is correct. I copied everything in app, so the folder of wsgi.py should be there as well.

Comment: I do still think including nginx will fix the problem, as the app is loaded(at least its visible on web preview.) Do you want to start a chat? It may be easier.

Comment: I don't see how nginx will help if the app is not working, but ok have a try! dunno how chat works, start it and i'll check where it is!

Comment: Well, the chat didn't work as I have less than 20 reputation. When I implement nginx, I use uwsgi.ini to start my app and well... it does refuse to start... So I am guessing something is wrong there as well..

Comment: Ok, so I just decided to load the website using Internet Explorer instead of Chrome and guess what... it loaded... @Yom86. Can you help me slightly to get the nginx going?

Comment: lol, what a joke! Programming can be depressing sometimes! Ok, are you keeping nginx in the same container or a different one?

Comment: Well, I have it in the same one and trying to run it using supervisor. As I previously said, I read somewhere that if they are in different containers when i use the socket it won't work. If you say it is better for them to be in different containers let it be then.

Comment: we are using proxy_pass and ip:port upstreams, so it works for sure. but its up to you. i don't see the point of putting both in same container. The idea of docker is to isolate services ones from the others and make containers talk together

Comment: As I said, I am fine with both, but I have already made the Dockerfile for both of them in 1 container, getting them in separate containers will require more work, won't it?

Comment: Ok, try like this for now. you can separate them after

Comment: Well, when I try like this I get **INFO gave up: app-uwsgi entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly**. I assume my uwsgi.ini is not set correctly. In the supervisord config file I have set it this : `command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --https :443 --ini uwsgi.ini`, and in docker-compose I changed the ports to 443 instead of 8000.

Comment: no need to use the uwsgi.ini. just use the same command ad the one we used ealier, and use port 8000 for django cause you can't have nginx and django listening the same port. In docker-compose, you need to expose both 443 and 8000

Comment: 443 for nginx, 8000 for django

Comment: It still connects with http and not https. How is django going to connect to nginx if uwsgi.ini is not being used?

Comment: django doesn't connect to Nginx, it listens to port 8000. When Nginx receives a request on port 443, it looks at it, and decides what server to send it to. If it decides to send it to django, it sends it to the django upstream, which is the django IP with port 8000

Comment: Well, I guess Nginx didn't hear my app on 8000 as it still does not work with https.

Comment: did you expose both 8000 and 443 in web container?

Comment: In docker-compose.yml I have under ports both 8000 and 443. I will update all the files now.

Comment: oh, you need to remove the first 2 lines in location / cause you added my lines but did not remove yours

Comment: I updated my nginx.conf file and yet no luck. Https is still not accepted. I edited the version above.

Comment: add this under the max size line: access_log /var/log/nginx/lb_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/lb_error.log; that way we will see if you get error and we will see the requests handled

Comment: Well, I updated the nginx.conf file and runned both containers and accessed one using `docker exec -it web /bin/bash` followed by `cat /var/log/nginx/lb_access.log` and nothing happend. Can it be that I am implementing nginx in the Dockerfile wrong?

Comment: Update on the issue - it now works. I had to install the ssl certificate in internet explorer.